# XMPPFramework: Trying to update nickname on VCard

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

This question is as simple as its title says: I'm trying to update a user nickname on his VCard but I cannot. I'm using this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        XMPPvCardTemp *myVcardTemp = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] myvCardTemp];
        [myVcardTemp setNickname:@"a_nickname"];
        [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:myVcardTemp];
    });
```

I cannot imagine why this piece of code don't want to work while the same piece, but updating photo, is working like a charm:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(anImage);
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            XMPPvCardTemp *myVcardTemp = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] myvCardTemp];
            [myVcardTemp setPhoto:imageData];
            [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:myVcardTemp];
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated... this is driving me crazy

NOTES: I'm using OpenFire as XMPP server

And this is the stanza the server returns me when I'm trying to update the nickname

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="7db55e68-cb18-4826-befd-0eb9269637aa@000.000.000.000" to="7db55e68-cb18-4826-befd-0eb9269637aa@000.000.000.000/2cfc4f88"><chat_jorges xmlns="vcard-temp"><NICKNAME>chat_jorges</NICKNAME></chat_jorges></iq>
```

(I changed my server's ip for 000.000.000.000)

Comment: maybe it is sutpid but did you try: setNICKNAME = @"your nickname" ?

Comment: well, XMPPvCardTemp didn't implement setNICKNAME, but setNickname as shown... but thank you :)

Comment: sorry. But the more I read your problem the more it is driving me crazy too. And if you push it as a data as well?? (wonder how it could but...)

Comment: Good point Frank, really good point... let me try...

Comment: Well, the setNickname method requires a NSString parameter not a NSData one... :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I WAS TOTALLY WRONG DON'T READ THIS

Actually when I read the source code of XMPP, I wonder how it could set a value.
In XMPPvCardTempBase.h :

```
#define XMPP_VCARD_SET_STRING_CHILD(Value, Name) NSXMLElement *elem = [self elementForName:(Name)];
//it looks like a get and not a set??
```

And in XMPPvCardTemp.m :

```
- (void)setNickname:(NSString *)nick {
    XMPP_VCARD_SET_STRING_CHILD(nick, @"NICKNAME");
}
```

Maybe there is something as KVC somewhere...
Can you try this in the source code:

```
 - (void)setNickname:(NSString *)nick {
       XMPP_VCARD_SET_STRING_CHILD(nick, @"NICKNAME") = nick ;
   }
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try right now. Thank you for your time. I'll give feedback :)

Comment: Actually if I use the tweak you proposed, XCode gives the error "expected expression". If you can see, the definition of the XMPP_VCARD_SET_STRING_CHILD already set "nick" as "Value"...

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, i didn't see the full implementation of the definition.

Comment: It seems that if I send presence just after update the nickname, the delegate method didReceivePresence will be fired on other devices, and then I can fire this code: [xmppRoster setNickname:@"name" forUser:[presence from]]; It seems to work as a patch by now... But it will be interesting to know the origin of this behavior